# How to open a file from the project in a native C++ unit test (Visual Studio)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-c++

I have a native C++ unit test project in Visual Studio (2012).
In one of my tests I would like to read a file included in my unit test project. Is it possible? What properties of the file should I set and what path should I use?

I added a test.txt file to my project (and tried to set its Content property to true). And in a unit test I tried to open the file with a relative path like this:

```
std::ifstream file("text.txt");
```

But it does not work.

I guess the file should be copied to the place from where the unit test runs. Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: use the full path such as "C:\\some_dir\\text.txt"

Comment: Even if you want to use a relative path ultimately, use a full path first just to eliminate any other causes of the problem.

Comment: With absolute paths I can open files without any problem. But that does not work for me, because I want these unit tests to work for every programmer on our team, so it is important to open the files contained by the project with relative paths.

Answer (score 10):

This can be accomplished by using the `__FILE__` macro, in my case I did like this:

```
//Returns my solution's directory
#define TEST_CASE_DIRECTORY GetDirectoryName(__FILE__)

string GetDirectoryName(string path){
    const size_t last_slash_idx = path.rfind('\\');
    if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx)
    {
        return path.substr(0, last_slash_idx + 1);
    }
    return "";
}

TEST_METHOD(MyTest)
{
    string filename = std::string(TEST_CASE_DIRECTORY) + "MyTestFile.txt";

    TestOutputForFile(filename);
}
```

Comment: Remember __FILE__ is a compile time path. This is the full path at the time of compile. This is usually fine as the unit tests are usually run on the same environment/machine as they are built .

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks.